# Finishing an app - getting the binary file?

Tags: iphone

I've finished developing my app and I want to release it. What is the binary file that apple is looking for in the submission for in iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

Zip the app bundle, or better yet, use the Organizer to upload.

Comment: my app name is aaz and exist in drive d please give me path of binary file

Comment: Please look at Apple's docs, they explain the procedure step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Build directory inside your project folder. There should be a folder in there called "Release". Inside that folder is `YourApp.app`. Zip it up and send it in.

Comment: i did it but occur below errors in application loader
1.info.plist does not contain a CFBundleResourceSpecification
2.Application failed codesign verification.the signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit apple provisioning portal to generate a distribution certificate for your app, then download it to your machine and in the end you have to build it up it with this certificate in xCode. 
There some tutorials on the provisioning page. So I hope you can make it.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action